# How to import external modules in riot js?

Tags: riot.js

Hi I'm new to riot I want to import an external module/ file in tag files

but getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` error any idea??

Comment: Actual source code would be helpful. I use browserify/riotify, so I just `require` them in the tag's script.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a whole lot to go off of from your question, but the problem is most likely that you're not using a build process. `import` statements are an ES6 feature and not yet supported in browsers. You'll need to use a transpiler (e.g. [Babel JS](https://babeljs.io/), etc.) to transpile your ES6 code into ES5 that will be supported in the browser. If you're new to building javascript, you may have some issues with building Riot. My process uses [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), Babel, and [Riot tag loader](https://github.com/riot/tag-loader). The setup can be pretty difficult for beginners but it's easy to find some great resources and walkthroughs out there. Your webpack config might look something like this when you're done:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './build'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
      test: /\.tag$/,
      loader: 'riot-tag-loader',
      enforce: 'pre'
    }, {
      test: /\.(js|tag)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    }
  ]}
}
```

If you don't feel like including babel, just use good ol' `require()`

e.g. `const utils = require('./utils.js')`)

But you'll still need a build process